# Timed Out Connection Error React to Express Server on EC2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2

Im trying to access my Node/Express Server using a fetch/axios GET request on React

This IP is the Private IP to the server so it has been Xed out

```
axios.get('http://172.xx.xx.xxx:5000/api')
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
```

This is Express Code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true}));


const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);



app.get('/api', cors(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("HELLO")

})
```

I get a *Error: Network Error*

Im assuming this is a secuirty policy on AWS EC2

However When i do a
**curl 172.xx.xxx.xxx:5000/api**

My Node server then prints out Hello, so it is accesible but not via the front end react. (This is curled on the same server running both Express/React

This is my Inbound rules, i havent touched any VPC stuff not sure if i need to
I enabled all ports just to check (not be the case in production)

[image]

I also do not have a firewall running on my server (nothing appeared when ufw status command was ran)

Where I am i going wrong for me to make a Request from React to Express

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT ADDED DEVELOPER TOOL SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of error from developer tools? Is it a CORS error or just says Network error?

Comment: I have added the screenshot as requested

Comment: P.S. Your private IP is unmasked in the second image - replace the image with a masked IP and change it on your instance as the changelog will still retain the image

Answer (score 0):

try to run:
`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`
from your ec2 instance

Comment: thanks for the reply this does not seem to have an affect on the issue

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't fully understand your requirement, I believe you have express/react running on same server and also you need to hit express from you local machine.

So here are my two cents:

- Inside same server, both would be able to access each other on localhost:. Hence running on production and since you are having single server use `localhost`. Expose only react's port i.e tcp `3000` on `0.0.0.0/0` & `::/0`
- If you are trying to hit express from local machine and localhost while trying to run react on localhost, you should be hitting public IP of your instance ex: 192.168.12.14:express-port, and would require opening up that port on tcp to `0.0.0.0/0` & `::/0`

Answer (score 0):

Reading through, Initially, my suggestion would have been that you install PM2 on your instance since it is a Node project, you can find it here https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2 (It keeps your server live and you can see with is running and stuffs). But, since you said it works with CURL, then you should check your Inbound rules. Here is an example [Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXjjZ.png)
Which just includes support of HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have modified the inbound rules to allow everything to remove this as a sticking point as in the question but it still doesnt like the request

Answer (score 0):

It is your browser that ends up making the request to your private IP address. CURLing works because once you've SSHd to either of your instances, your private IP address is valid.

When the React app makes this request in the browser, the private IP address doesn't actually go to the instance as you'd expect.

You'll need a reverse proxy server or load balancer that can proxy requests and change their origin from public IP to private IP. NGINX or http-proxy-middleware can help you accomplish this.